# Unsigned char* в std::string

Tags: boost, изображения, сокет, c++

Получаю jpeg изображение из raw с помощью jpeglib

```
struct jpeg_compress_struct cinfo;
struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr;
unsigned char* outBuf = NULL;
unsigned long outBufSize = 0;
{
    cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr);
    jpeg_create_compress(&cinfo);
    jpeg_mem_dest(&cinfo, &outBuf, &outBufSize);
    cinfo.image_width = width;
    cinfo.image_height = height;
    cinfo.input_components = 3;
    cinfo.in_color_space = JCS_RGB;
    jpeg_set_defaults(&cinfo);
    jpeg_set_quality(&cinfo, JPEG_QUALITY, TRUE);
    jpeg_start_compress(&cinfo, TRUE);
    JSAMPROW row_pointer[1];
    std::vector<JOCTET> rgbLine(3 * width);
    while (cinfo.next_scanline < cinfo.image_height) {
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
            std::fill(&rgbLine[3 * i], &rgbLine[3 * i] + 3, rawGrayImage[cinfo.next_scanline * stride + i]);
        }
        row_pointer[0] = &rgbLine[0];
        jpeg_write_scanlines(&cinfo, row_pointer, 1);
    }
    jpeg_finish_compress(&cinfo);
}
```

Размер полученного изображения:

```
outBufSize: 210067
```

Хочу переслать его по boost сокету.

```
std::string str(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&outBuf[0]));
int n = write(socket_, buffer(str));
std::cout << "bytes received: " << n << std::endl;
std::cout << "str size: " << str.size() << std::endl;
```

в итоге выводит

```
bytes received: 4
str size: 4
```

Никакого изображенния в браузере не появляется.
Правильно ли я преобразовываю unsigned char* в std::string?

Comment: А почему вообще вы пересылаете строку? Пересылать надо набор байт.

Comment: это работает. я пробовал пересылать таким образом jpeg картинку с диска, она нормально доходит. Конвертация тоже должна быть верной, так как я пересылал полученное jpeg изображение по линуксовым и win сокетам.

Comment: @feelGood: Если бы это работало, у вас не было бы проблемы. Я бы посоветовал пересылать именно байты.

Comment: а как это сделать?

Comment: @feelGood: А что у вас за функция write? Она по идее должна уметь принимать массив байт.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Есть подозрение что строка сформировалась не совсем верно.

Попробуйте так:

`std::string str(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&outBuf[0]), outBufSize);`

В случае с string(const char *) к конструкторе делатся пробег по входной строке пока не встретится `0`, это означает что строчка кончилась. Может быть здесь `0` встретился в 4 байте.